# MySQL JOIN via parent ID

Tags: mysql, join

I am stuck for several days now. I'm not sure if my DB design is inefficient or just my query is wrong.
What would be best solution regarding performance?

I have tables as follows:

```
View:
+--------+--------------+
+ idEmpl + idDepartment +
+--------+--------------+
+ 1      + 1            +
+ 2      + 1            +
+ 3      + 2            +
+--------+--------------+

# customer is a supplier for department of employee
Table supplier:         
+--------+----------------+----------------+
+ idEmpl + idCustomer     + nrSupplier     + 
+--------+----------------+----------------+
+ 1      + 2              + 0815           +
+ 1      + 4              + 0816           +
+ 2      + 5              + 0817           +
+ 3      + 4              + 4711           +
+--------+----------------+----------------+

# customer is a manufacturer for department of employee
Table manufacturer:         
+--------+----------------+----------------+
+ idEmpl + idCustomer     + nrManufacturer + 
+--------+----------------+----------------+
+ 1      + 2              + a111           +
+ 2      + 5              + a113           +
+ 3      + 4              + b492           +
+--------+----------------+----------------+

Wanted result after query:
+--------+------------+------------+----------------+
+ idEmpl + idCustomer + nrSupplier + nrManufacturer +
+--------+------------+------------+----------------+
+ 1      + 2          + 0815       + a111           +
+ 1      + 4          + 0816       + NULL           +
+ 2      + 5          + 0816       + a112           +
+--------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

Since idCustomer is no existing manufacturer for the employees department there should be NULL but my recent query Returns 'b492' from employee 3 and his department 2.

If I would add idDepartment to the tables supplier and manufacturer I assume would have no problems.
But I thought storing child-ID, parent-ID wouldn't be needed.

Both queries wont select idDperatment=1 only..

```
SELECT v.*, s.nrSupplier, m.nrManufacturer
FROM view v
LEFT JOIN supplier s     ON (v.idEmpl=s.idEmpl AND v.idDepartment=1)
LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON (v.idEmpl=m.idEmpl AND v.idDepartment=1);
```

This will return of employee only but not the entire department and supplier/manufacturer might be set from different employees.

```
SELECT v.*, s.nrSupplier, m.nrManufacturer
FROM view v
LEFT JOIN supplier s     ON (v.idEmpl=s.idEmpl)
LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON (v.idEmpl=m.idEmpl)
 WHERE v.idDepartment=1;
```

This will still select 1st found nrSupplier even thou not related to idDepartement

```
SELECT v.*, s.nrSupplier, m.nrManufacturer
FROM view v
LEFT JOIN supplier s     ON (v.idCustomer=s.idCustomer AND vcc.idDepartment=1)
LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON (v.idCustomer=m.idCustomer AND vcc.idDepartment=1);
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Comment: Also, I'm confused. You mention performance, but don't seem to have a functioning query. Surely a slow, working query is better than a fast, non-working one.

Comment: I mention Performance because I thought of might needing Sub queries or just split it to 4 queries. Adding a row idDepartment would propably solve the problem but I think there must be a way I currently don't know or see, to: JOIN tables on a parents ID which is not included in JOINed tables.

Answer (score 0):

Join `manufacturer` table by  both `idEmpl` and `idCustomer` to get that result as:

```
SELECT v.*,s.idCustomer, s.nrSupplier, m.nrManufacturer
FROM view v
LEFT JOIN supplier s     ON (v.idEmpl=s.idEmpl)
LEFT JOIN manufacturer m ON (v.idEmpl=m.idEmpl and s.idCustomer=m.idCustomer )
WHERE v.idDepartment=1;
```

Comment: Using idEmpl restricts me to the eployees records itself and not ist Departments records. My bad. I set it to idCustomer but also then at JOINed tables I get 1st found even of other Department returned.